# Querying calendar events even if they do not have any for the day

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Hey everyone, I am trying to figure out a way to query my mysql server so that even if a company does not have anything posted for the day and the user clicks on their logo, it still adds them to the list.

That sounds a little confusing so let me try to explain it another way.

Say I have 3 companies in my database:

```
Comp1
Comp2
Comp3
```

And Comp1 & Comp3 have something for today on the calendar but Comp2 does not. I still need it to populate and place that company on the page but have something along the lines of "nothing on the calendar for today". The other 2 companies (Comp1 & Comp3) would show the calendar posting for that day.

This is the code I have right now:

```
 SELECT clientinfo.id, clientinfo.theCompName, clientinfo.theURL, clientinfo.picURL,
 clientinfo.idNumber, clientoffers.idNumber, clientoffers.theDateStart, clientoffers.theDateEnd
 FROM clientinfo, clientoffers
 WHERE clientinfo.accountStats = 'OPEN'
 AND clientinfo.idNumber = clientinfo.idNumber
 AND '2010-05-08' BETWEEN clientoffers.theDateStart AND clientoffers.theDateEnd
 GROUP BY clientinfo.idNumber
 ORDER BY clientinfo.theCompName ASC
```

That executes just fine but for Comp2, it just places the calendar info from Comp1 into it when it really doesn't have anything.

The output looks like this:

```
Comp1 | 2010-05-08 | this is the calendar event 1 | etc etc
Comp2 | 2010-05-08 | this is the calendar event 1 | etc etc <-- this should have no date or event just Comp2
comp3 | 2010-05-09 | this is the calendar event 2 | etc etc
```

What the output needs to look like is:

```
Comp1 | 2010-05-08 | this is the calender event 1 | etc etc
Comp2 |            |                              | etc etc
comp3 | 2010-05-09 | this is the calender event 2 | etc etc
```

I'll also add that if there is no event on the calendar for a company then there's no idNumber in the clientoffer table. So in the example above, Comp2 does not have any information in the clientoffer table so I am guessing that's why when I run my query that it just duplicates the last record's data since it can not find a match in the clientinfo.idnumber = clientoffer.idnumber

Any help would be great :o)

David

**UPDATED #2**

The DB structure:

```
clientinfo table:

theCompName | idNumber
comp 1      | 513200
comp 2      | 8944
comp 3      | 03884

clientoffers table:

idNumber | theDateStart | theDateEnd
513200   | 2010-05-08   | 2010-05-08
03884    | 2010-05-07   | 2010-05-09
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is the purpose of `AND clientinfo.idNumber = clientinfo.idNumber`? Did you mean `FROM clientinfo JOIN clientoffers ON clientinfo.idNumber = clientoffers.idNumber`?

Comment: Can you post in table structures for the two tables? Not all columns, just those that are relevant. I suspect this is as simple as performing a left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my go at it. I have:

- Reduced number of columns so its easier to see whats going on
- Transformed this query to a `LEFT JOIN` query
- Moved the date comparison from `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause
- Removed the `GROUP BY` clause: if a company has two events for same date, two rows are returned

So we have:

```
SELECT
    clientinfo.idNumber,
    clientinfo.theCompName,
    clientoffers.theDateStart,
    clientoffers.theDateEnd
FROM      clientinfo
LEFT JOIN clientoffers ON
    ( clientinfo.idNumber = clientoffer.idNumber) AND
    ( '2010-05-08' BETWEEN clientoffers.theDateStart AND clientoffers.theDateEnd )
WHERE    clientinfo.accountStats = 'OPEN'
ORDER BY clientinfo.theCompName ASC
```

I still need to know what primary and foreign keys are being used by the two tables. Let me know and I'll fix the query.

Comment: Yours seemed to work without given me an error on the thedatestart if i was checking to see if it equaled null. Thanks, Salman. Though, i tried to put the ifnull(theDateStart, 'na') in your code and it gave me an error as it does for the code lexu has below here. Anyway i can make it put 'na' instead of null?

Comment: I'm going to have to take the check away because i just tested it more and it seems that i can not get the value of clientinfo.idNumber to show if clientinfo.idNumber <> clientoffers.idNumber. Which again, wont be there unless the company has something on the calender. But if it does not i need it to get the idNumber from the clientinfo table instead.

Comment: Ideally, you should not mix the string `na` in your start/end dates, you'll get unpredictable results because of casting. Check for nulls in your ASP code instead e.g. `if IsNull(rs("theDateStart")) then`. Alternatively add a column in your query that contains 0 or 1 e.g. `CASE WHEN theDateStart IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END AS boolHasOffers`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood correctly ... but does this help:

```
SELECT clientinfo.id
     , clientinfo.theCompName
     , clientinfo.theURL
     , clientinfo.picURL
     , clientinfo.idNumber
     , IFNULL(clientoffers.idNumber,-1)
     , IFNULL(clientoffers.theDateStart,'')  
     , IFNULL(clientoffers.theDateEnd,'')
  FROM clientinfo 
  LEFT JOIN clientoffers 
    ON (      clientinfo.idNumber = clientoffers.idNumber
         AND '2010-05-08' BETWEEN clientoffers.theDateStart 
                              AND clientoffers.theDateEnd
       )
 WHERE clientinfo.accountStats = 'OPEN'
 GROUP BY clientinfo.idNumber
 ORDER BY clientinfo.theCompName ASC
```

You would have to check for an offer ID of -1 and then display the logo.

---

The idea here is to select all clients from clientinfo and show the joined info from clientoffers where it exists and a null if it doesn't exist. That's what the left join syntx does.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply there Lexu. Though it executed, i am looking for something that STILL displays all 3 company regardless of if they have something for that day on the calender or not. It seems your code only displays if the company HAS something for that they and does not show anything else if not...

Comment: @StealthRT: sigh, I forgot to move the conditions into the left join. plz try again

Comment: I tried your code out again and yes, it now does show all 3 companies but when i go and execute it in my asp page, it comes with an error on the theDateStart table for the company that does not have anything which in turns shoots an error. I tried an if-then to say "if rst("theDateStart") = "na" then.... else.... but it still has the error on the theDateStart. "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." I've used the ifNull(theDateStart, 'NA') but it doesn't seem to work?